# automated testing on a mature codebase

Tags: automated-tests

I'm working with a large mature php codebase that I'm considering making a case for automated testing for to the management. As part of this I want to have the core of a usable testing suite in place to demo the impacts on our completion times ect. Only thing is, I'm pretty much a novice at automated testing myself and theres a couple of real life considerations I'm not altogether clear on.

For one thing how do I include my tests in git? I don't want to push them live!

For another I clearly don't want to create dependencies in the production code on a testing tool. So should I be writing the tests to load the main application into them as a preamble to the actual tests? (This would seem to imply a mirror directory structure for tests is needed in our development environments).

Lastly I am leaning toward PHPtest and/or selenium to run the show. In particular I want to test browser test results including html and subsequent js and ajax operations. Selenium seems ideal for that but I'm unclear on how I would integrate it into the codebase. I assume its Javascript but I'm unclear on that. The remaining features that aren't user accessible would then be tested by PHPtest, a fairly small number of items I would assume. Does that seem in any way sane?

Comment: Actually a mature codebase is good for creating automated testing environment. If you are churning out regular builds, you can present a case to your management where you can showcase automating regression test cases. You may also want to create a smoke/sanity test pack as a POC to ensure code quality for test builds.

Comment: @PankajJaju You may also want to create a smoke/sanity test pack as a POC to ensure code quality for test builds - I understood some of those words :)

Comment: If you can identify some broad test cases which touches all important corners (modules) of your application, then you can use those tests as a starting point to sell to your managers how automating them will ensure that the changes in the build isn't breaking any major functionality. So you are basically reducing the risk of major error in prod in case you haven't tested the build fully.